# How to log each and every function / method call in a Django project?

Tags: python, django, debugging, logging

Is it possible to log each and every function and method that is being called in a large Django project? I came across [this](https://gist.github.com/brendano/16173) but I cannot place decorators on every class method or a function. I am trying to find something like this for the whole project so that I can get to the root of how django and the project that I am working on handles everything.

Comment: have you checked django debug toolbar?

Comment: @ruddra Yes. It doesn't show what I am looking for unfortunately.

Comment: Do you need to do that at app level? I'm asking 'casue `uwsgi` do that for you.

Comment: @trinchet Well, app level can be really good. But how do I do that? And what information can I get from there?